# Order custom post type is beign ignored

Tags: custom-post-types, php, query, order

I have a custom post type "car". I've created a loop to show all the titles of that post type. I want to show them alphabetically. But the order is ignored.

```
<?php
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'car',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'DESC'
)
);
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

the_title();

endwhile; wp_reset_query(); 
?>
```

The order output is the same order of the input. So I've added Volkswagen Tiguan first, so that is shown first and not Audi A1 (for example).

Comment: `order` should be `ASC` if you want them displayed alphabetically. i.e. (1, 2, 3, a, b, c, d)

Answer (score -1):

quick info, use this to know what is being return:

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'car',
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'asc'
)
);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($loop);

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Also I believe is better at the end reset the postdata to be sure that nothing is being change in the database. For all I had read this is good to use everytime we open a new WP_Query.